# ShellScript comando 'cd'

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script

Qual comando que eu uso para ir direto para pasta de *login* sem ter que colocar meu nome exemplo `cd home/leonardovillela`.?

Comment: o comando é o mesmo, mas tem um atalho pra pasta home: `cd ~`

Comment: @Bacco, se quiser responder a pergunta me avisa, acabei postando uma resposta mas não vi seu comentário.

Comment: @Wakim nao postei como resposta mais por achar que não é uma pergunta no escopo do site, e esse tipo de coisa acho que cabe mais como comment mesmo. De qq forma, grato por perguntar.

Comment: @Bacco, na minha opinião está dentro do escopo sim, `shell-script` é uma linguagem de programação... Assim como dúvidas relativas a arquivos `batch` estão dentro do escopo, acredito que `shell-script` também (http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1266/cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-arquivo-bat-entra-no-escopo-do-sopt).

Comment: Pra mim a mera consulta de sintaxe de comando não é uma dúvida de shell-script, independente de onde o comando vai ser usado (mas é perfeitamente válido sua opinião ser diferente, afinal estamos em comunidade ;) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta usar o comando `cd ~`, com ele você irá para o diretório *home* do usuário atual.

Comment: Outras formas seriam: apenas `cd` e `cd $HOME`.